# How do I get a Monitor to go straight to black on stage?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, desktop

I'm working props for a theater in upstate new york. We have a rather unique problem with our current show. We have three computer monitors on stage, each of these is attached to a handful of computers which we are switching between during the show. (the show takes place in an office, each computer is in a cubicle)

The problem is that we need to the screens to go black, not video black but powered down black, whenever we have a quick black out. This happens often through the show. Every solution I've found so far results in the "no signal" screen blaring out of an otherwise black stage, looking terrible. Video black is too visible as well.

Any ideas for how to achieve this? Perhaps a specific monitor, or a program I'm unable to find?

Comment: So the computers are connected to the big monitors?? Via HDMI?? Which OS on the computers??

Comment: unfourtunately, modern backlit monitors will not display true black unless they are powered off in a dark room. there will always be some illumination if it is on. you could mask off the edges of the screen with gaffers tape to limit it a little, but a monitor is a light producing device at its most basic, so you are probably not going to be able to get what you want by modifying the output in any particular way. just pull the plug

Comment: The computers are connected with VGA cables to a switcher, which in turn connects to a few computers. This lets us fake time jumps by switching machines on the back end. The computers are running mostly winXP or more recent, but there are a couple macs that run videos fullscreened.

Comment: There must be some way.  The computer can signal a monitor to go to power save mode, which turns the LCD backlight off.  It might still leave the power indicator turned on, but just cover that with black tape.

Comment: @Kieran Neat problem.  You should edit your question with all the equipment and OS you're using.  Have you considered hooking them up to a central power bar (or PDU) and simply switching them off?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of media you present on your screens but I think this would work. What I do (on linux) is extending the monitor rather than duplicating it. Then I set up two workspaces:

1. One workspace has the actual content on the second (extended) screen.
2. The second workspace has a full black PNG shown on full-screen, on the second screen too. I sometimes limit my XFCE panel to only one screen and set the secondary screen's background to black (`#000000`).
3. I then disable the transition animation between desktops and as soon as I need a black screen I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, and press it again to go back and forth between them.
4. If I need to change content while the screen is black, I just drag drop the window to the first screen of the current workspace (using the workspace panel plugin on XFCE), change the media, and drag-drop it again to the second screen of the other desktop to wait there to be shown.

**Update**:

Additionally, you can control the power on or the standby state of a monitor or screen if you are using X.org:

For example, to suspend (or sleep) the monitor:

```
xset dpms force standby
```

Then you can reactivate it by simply moving the mouse or pressing a key.

These are other available options (they essentially do the same on certain monitors):

- standby
- suspend
- off
- on

Of course this only works if your monitor has DPMS (Energy Star) features. But beware, this is slow: the screen can actually have a small **delay** of about ~2 seconds **before turning on again**.

Comment: Sounds like this would not actually go to powered down black.  (Where the LCD backlight is turned off.)

Comment: Read my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Display Power Off](http://sourceforge.net/projects/doff/) is an open-source Windows utility that puts all displays to sleep.  It has a configuration ini file with a few settings.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the solution is to wire all the display power wires to a single electrical outlet or power strip. When you want the displays to go off, you just hit the switch that turns off that outlet, and all the displays turn off right then and there. Full power-off, not video black, and no "No connection" screen!