# Turn ON display with a batch or powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

We have a computer connected to a large vizio flat screen that displays secure information and it is always on. I have a script running with task scheduler to shut off only the display at a certain time each day.  Once the script runs the tv display goes into powersaving mode.
Is there a script I can run to turn the display back on at a certain time each morning?
I'm using powerrcfg in a batch file to shut off only the display but I can't seem to get one that turns it back on.

Comment: Simply go for an ultra low-tech solution and buy a time switch. :)

Comment: Can't `xset` help you? http://superuser.com/questions/783898/how-do-i-get-a-monitor-to-go-straight-to-black-on-stage/783902#783902

Comment: How exactly are you using Powercfg to turn off the display?

Comment: A SendKey should work. The batch file needs to be run as the logged in user, not as system like the default with scheduled tasks. Maybe give this a try: [Press Keyboard keys using a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) , there are several options to wake a machine from sleep and its several sleep states, which may be the problem with it not coming out of it when you put it to sleep.  If you attempt to wake it from a sleepstate it is not currently in (say, wake it from 1, while the machine is in 2), it may not respond as expected.

If I read that page correctly, you can set it up to have wake from sleep enabled, and possibly preprogram a device that you want to use to wake the monitor from sleep.

Command: powercfg –devicequery wake_programmable – Lists devices that are user-configurable to wake the computer from a (specific*) sleep state.

powercfg –devicequery wake_armed – Lists devices that are currently configured to wake the computer from any sleep state.

Adding a remote might work or plugging in a computer might work, which you can do with command: powercfg –deviceenablewake devicename

For full reference, check the link.

- text inside ()'s by me.